# EngineId on snmpv3

Tags: java, snmp

I am working on upgrading snmpv2c to snmpv3 in our product for sending traps.
I've just started to get acquainted, so I have couple of questions related to snmpv3:

1. What is the purpose of EngineId?
2. I know that EngineId can auto-generated, so on which criteria it need to generate?
3. I have v2agent running on XXXX host with configurations "host: [local host Ip], port: 161, community: public". How I should configure iReasoning MIB browser (Do you know better?) in my local host to recieve traps from agent?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3411 the standard only asks for uniqueness inside an administration domain, so any approach feasible is ok. If you don't have a good way to auto generate that, leave it to the device user.

Answer (score 0):

Each SNMPv3 agent has an **engine ID** that uniquely identifies the agent/device.

SNMPv3 TRAPs use the engineID of the local application sending the trap rather than the engineID of the remote application. This means that you have to create users in your remote user database with a bit more care and need to create one for every engineID you wish to send traps from.

I'd suggest using **NetDecision TrapVision** to receive and handle SNMP traps. It fully supports SNMPv3. Please note that you'll need to create security profiles (USM) using **NetDecision SNMP User Manager** and associate them with trap sending entity in Security Settings of the app.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually testing snmpv3 for HPE 16gb FC interconnect modules for the new synergy platform.  Wrt engine ID it comes from the device you want to send inform requests from. Traps do not require an engine ID, just a user.  If you want more security, the user does require authentication protocol, such as, MD5, and an encryption protocol such as AES or SHA1